# Send data to laravel with Android volley

Tags: android, laravel, parameter-passing, android-volley

I want to send the user-id data I received with android to laravel.
codes for android;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String userId;

Button send;
private static final String KEY_USERNAME ="userId" ;
String insertUrl ="http://127.0.0.1:8000/registerDevices";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    userId= "12345";

    send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPush);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            registerUser();
        }
    });

}


public void registerUser(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,userId);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

My **route** in laravel;

Route::post('/registerDevices', 'RegisterController@registerdevices');

```
public function registerdevices(Request $request)
{
    \Log::info('api call from andriod');
   $jsonPostedData = Input::get('userId');


    return $this->service->registerdevices($jsonPostedData);

}
```

my code does not work and the error it gives;

> java.net.ConnectException:Connection Refused

Can you help me?

Comment: did you add internet permissions in app manifest?

Comment: yes Of course but  it gives same error

Comment: Ensure your emulator has internet connection. What is the value of insertUrl argument in the stringRequest?